# Smtp authentication (Login Test) without sending email

Tags: c#, smtp, pop3, smtpclient, smtp-auth

The currnt need is to perform SMTP authentication using given username, password, and authentication mode(CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN).
I just need to perform a Login Test and not send any mail and reply with a message box as Login test Successful or Fail.
I have tried out ways to authenticate using SMTPClient but the credentials are authenticated only when one is sending a mail.
I have looked around ways to do this but all seem to authenticate by sending a mail.
How does one do it without sending a mail?

After that I need to perform a "POP before SMTP Utilization Test" with both Ping Test and Login Test(using pop server, username, password, port number).

Thanks & Regards,
Jatin.

Answer (score 1):

Use TcpClient and RFC 5321, RFC 2554 to implement part of SMTP protocol. For example look at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient implementation of Mono

Answer (score 0):

try testing the credentials by configuring the outlook setting and dont sent the test mail.
Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: what i understood is, you only need to check whether the credentials are correct or not and while this checking process email must not be fired! If I am correct, then i have tested my credentials with OUtlook, without forwarding the email.

Comment: I am using Thunderbird....But the question is not about using Thunderbird or Outlook... Its about how can I test the already settings(or some vague settings from user for test) by coding using c#. I am actualy creating a connection test and the authentication is working only when i send mail using
<pre>
<code>
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = "Server";
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@example.com", "PASSWORD");
</code>
</pre>
How to do without sending a mail.?